# How to show nested items in list view

Tags: windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I'm working in WinRT application, I have list of folders with nested child folders. I need to show it like Windows 8.1 Mail application folders. Refer windows 8.1 Mail. Parent folders and sub folders displayed like this

```
Fodler1 
  ..Child1
  ..Child2
    ..Child 2A
Folder2
  ..Child1
  ..Child2
```

I need to display like this using Listview or List box, Any idea?

Comment: Its impractical to expect us to look up the reference. Please provide the code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `ItemTemplateSelector` and flatten your folder tree into a list where items have templates that match the folder nesting levels. Make it so that when the folder items get clicked - their children get removed/inserted into the collection (make sure to use `ObservableCollection` to support monitoring changes to the list).

There's a sample in WinRT XAML Toolkit.

- [View](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample/Views/MainPage.xaml)
- [View model](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample/ViewModels/MainPageViewModel.cs)